# How secure is VeraCrypt by IDRIX when compared to the now defunct TrueCrypt?

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

I would like to know how safe is [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) by [IDRIX](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/) to use when compared to [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/), which as the webiste states is unsecure. Had IDRIX managed to fix all the security bugs in TrueCrypt or is there still something missing (I want to use VeraCrypt on my Windows 7 Home Premium OS which does not support BitLocker To Go). Thanks.

Comment: well, per https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/ VeraCrypt is a derivation of Truecrypt 7.1a, but with some settings cranked up a bit, and some bug fixes, and re-branded UI screens. It is open source so you can examine the code, but of course, without formal public audit, there is no way to verify their claims. That the formal audit of truecrypt came out looking pretty good bodes well.

Comment: Where did you get the information about the formal public audit? Who audits these things and is there a website where I can see the results of such audits and related information? Thanks.

Comment: the https://opencryptoaudit.org/ project, but I recommend you start here to gain a little context: http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/04/truecrypt-audit-finds-no-evidence-of-backdoors-or-malicious-code/

Comment: Do you trust them?  If you do use Veracrypt if not use the last version of Truecrypt that supports encrypting, if you don't trust Truecrypt adjust your requirements for cross-platform encryption

Comment: One of the neat things about crypto as an academic pursuit is that it uses statistics to eliminate emotionally based "trust" from the equation, but just because an algorithm has advantage of at least 51% over an adversary in a given circumstance, does not necessarily mean that an implementation of that algorithm is equally "trustworthy", nor that the practical integration with the environment is so (SALSA20 is a strong algorithm but if you use it for FDE [a bad choice for a stream cipher] and make sloppy mistakes in how you solicit and store keys) it is weak. thats why audits are important.

Answer (score 1):

Veracrypt should be more secure than Truecrypt because it has addressed existing security vulnerabilities from Truecrypt, and it has added new security features as well.

According to [VeraCrypt FAQ](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/FAQ.html):

> **What's the difference between TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt?**
>
> VeraCrypt adds enhanced security to the algorithms used for system and partitions encryption making it immune to new developments in brute-force attacks.
> It also solves many vulnerabilities and security issues found in TrueCrypt.
> As an example, when the system partition is encrypted, TrueCrypt uses PBKDF2-RIPEMD160 with 1000 iterations whereas in VeraCrypt we use 327661. And for standard containers and other partitions, TrueCrypt uses at most 2000 iterations but VeraCrypt uses 655331 for RIPEMD160 and 500000 iterations for SHA-2 and Whirlpool.
> This enhanced security adds some delay only to the opening of encrypted partitions without any performance impact to the application use phase. This is acceptable to the legitimate owner but it makes it much harder for an attacker to gain access to the encrypted data.

Veracrypt has fixed most if not all the security vulnerabilities that were found in audit of Truecrypt 7.1a ([Security Assessment of VeraCrypt: fixes and evolutions from TrueCrypt](https://blog.quarkslab.com/security-assessment-of-veracrypt-fixes-and-evolutions-from-truecrypt.html)) and it has gone through its own audit as well ([The VeraCrypt Audit Results – Open Source Technology Improvement Fund](https://ostif.org/the-veracrypt-audit-results/))

Even TrueCrypt, with its vulnerabilities, have fared quite well, so I am confident that VeraCrypt will provide even better protection.  I am not aware of single case where TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt encryption has been cracked ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt)), with exception to cases where passwords were easily guessable or when password were obtained via interrogation.